# IE11 flex issues with wrapping content

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I have the following code which has four columns wrapped over 2 rows using flex.  In chrome and firefox, this works perfectly with the first item taking it's own row and then the second row, all the items match the tallest in that row.

However in IE11, the items in the second row match the tallest item out of all 4 (rather than just on it's own row) meaning that there is a lot of white space created in the second row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.grid-column {
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(3),
.grid-column:nth-child(4) {
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.widget-article {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(1) .widget-article {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.widget-article__content {
  background: #313B3D;
  color: #ffffff;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.widget-article__content a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-container--listing grid-container--full-half-quarter">
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / column -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to make IE behave like chrome and firefox without changing the html structure?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5365ycpu/ I see 5 blocks in 2 rows, is this correct?

Comment: @Pete your issue most likely is because you have flex containers which is also a flex item. In IE11 this will often give you unexpected results. In the specs, it says this is ok however I find it on IE11 this occurs quite often and I have avoided doing that. You got a lot of code and I have no IE11

Comment: not sure what you mean block elements, you got flex containers everywhere and the children are auto flex items. If you can simplify your code, this would be much easier to figure out. Right now there are so many divs and safari simulating ie11 shows everything on its own row. Even the text content area are flex, they look like they can just be normal block elements

Comment: please read my comment about IE11 not liking flex containers which is also flex items. I am sure it can be simplified more, there are way too many layers of divs and whatnot for a simplified example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace flexbox for most elements except `.container` using `display: table`. Result:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid-container {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

.grid-column {
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 24px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(3),
.grid-column:nth-child(4) {
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.widget-article {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.widget-article > * {
  display: table-row;
}

.grid-column:first-child .widget-article > * {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.widget-article__content {
  background: #313B3D;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
}

.widget-article__content a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container grid-container--listing grid-container--full-half-quarter">
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-column">
    <div class="widget-article widget-article--full widget-article--featured widget-article--theme-3">
      <div class="media-asset">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/986x553" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="widget-article__content">
        <div class="widget-article__header">
          <h3 class="widget-article__title">
            <a class="widget-article__title-link" href="#">
                        Crash-tested landscape furniture: why functional will no longer do...
                </a>
          </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-article__footer">
          <div class="widget-article__meta">
            <div class="widget-article__meta-left">
              <div class="meta-details">
                <div class="meta-details__author">
                  <p><a class="meta-details__author-link" href="#">CHRISTOPHER HAINES</a></p>
                </div>
                <div class="meta-details__date">
                  <p>MONDAY 5TH JUNE, 2017</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / column -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm thanks but the whole site is using gridl so I would have to rewrite everything.  This is the only thing I am having problems with.  If needs be, I will just split the two rows onto separate lines, but +1 for the effort.

Comment: @Pete My fault, `display: inline-block` is not needed here. Replaced flexbox only for nested items.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in IE11 is that it uses the intrinsic height of the image.

Although you've set the width of the image containers:

```
.grid-column:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(3),
.grid-column:nth-child(4) {
  min-width: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
}
```

... which is enough to get the layout to work in Chrome and Firefox, these rules are not enough to alter the image's natural dimensions in IE11.

So consider adding something like this to your code:

```
 /* pixel units for illustration purposes only */

.grid-column:nth-child(2) img {
  height: 250px;
}

.grid-column:nth-child(3) img,
.grid-column:nth-child(4) img {
  height: 125px;
}
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/tsvo3e9d/)

Percentage heights are probably preferable to pixels, but that will take some work setting heights on ancestors. Since I don't know exactly what you want, I just used pixels for the demo. There may also be other sizing options you can use.

But the bottom line is, you need to override the intrinsic dimensions of the image for the layout to work in IE11.

Comment: Unfortunately the images need to be responsive by width so I cannot set their height

Comment: I figured as much. But that's the deal with IE11, a browser notorious for rendering problems.